# How we can solve linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

How we can solve following linear system of equations?

> $A_{1x}=ia(A_1+A_2)$,
>
> $A_{2x}=ia(A_1-A_2),$
>
> $A_{1t}=(ia/2)A_1-A_2$,
>
> $A_{2t}=A_1+(ia/2)A_2$,

where $A_1=A_1(x,t)$ and $A_2=A_2(x,t)$ and $a$ is a parameter independent of $x$ and $t$.

And $A_{1x}$ means partial derivative of $A_{1}$ w.r.t $x$.

Comment: What are the solving variables?

Comment: @Graubner $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are solving variables

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** add the first two equations together, then take the derivative with respect to $x$. You get $$A_{1x}+A_{2x}=2iaA_1\\(A_1+A_2)_{xx}=2iA_{1x}=-2a^2(A_1+A_2)$$
Now do the subtraction:
$$A_{1x}-A_{2x}=2iaA_2\\(A_1-A_2)_{xx}=2iA_{2x}=-2a^2(A_1-A_2)$$
Let's call $f=A_1+A_2$ and $g=A_1-A_2$. Solve for $f$ and $g$ then get $A_1=\frac{f+g}{2}$ and $A_2=\frac{f-g}{2}$. This will give the $x$ dependent part. Proceed similarly with the last two equations to get the time dependence.

Comment: I Can't understand clearly, can you provide me more detail

Comment: I've added a few more steps to my answer.

Comment: thanks, hope this will help

Comment: I have tried it, but this makes $A_{2}$ trivial, because $f$ and $g$ gives same exponential function

Comment: Maybe not. It depends on initial conditions